# The default "inset" property padding. ListItemText Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm styling a nested list in a React app using material-ui. The default "inset" property padding is to large (56px) so I'm trying to override that default value. But I can't.
any suggestions? Thank you !!

```
     <Fragment>
        <ListItem button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <ListItemText
            primary="Zones"            
            primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'subtitle2' }}
        />
          {this.state.open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
        </ListItem>
        <Collapse in={this.state.open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <List component="div" disablePadding>
            <ListItem button             
              component={Link}
              to={`${this.props.match.url}/zone/all-zones`}
              onClick={THIS.handleMenuOpen}
            >
              <ListItemText
                inset                
                primary="Show all"
                primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'subtitle2' }}
              />
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Collapse>
      </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the [inset prop](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-text/#props) on `ListItemText` is to align text of items that don't have an icon with the text of items that do (see the [Inset List demo](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#inset-list)). It is **not** for indenting nested list items.

If you look at the [Nested List demo](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#nested-list), you will find that the indent is done via `paddingLeft` applied to the nested list items. In the demo, this is set to 32px (`theme.spacing(4)`), but you can set this to whatever you want it to be.

Here is the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/bhnby) from the Nested List demo:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ListSubheader from "@material-ui/core/ListSubheader";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";
import InboxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox";
import DraftsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Drafts";
import SendIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Send";
import ExpandLess from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import StarBorder from "@material-ui/icons/StarBorder";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  },
  nested: {
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4)
  }
}));

export default function NestedList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <List
      component="nav"
      aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
      subheader={
        <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
          Nested List Items
        </ListSubheader>
      }
      className={classes.root}
    >
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <SendIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Sent mail" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <DraftsIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <InboxIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
        {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
      </ListItem>
      <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        <List component="div" disablePadding>
          <ListItem button className={classes.nested}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <StarBorder />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Starred" />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Collapse>
    </List>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. What happens is that I have a menu that groups several menus. And I wanted them to look nested. With your advice I did it by putting paddingLeft: 20

Answer (score 0):

```
Group-Menu

        <List component="nav" aria-label="patient-group">
            <ListItem>
                <ListItemText
                    primary="patients"
                    primaryTypographyProps={{variant:'button' }}
                />
            </ListItem>
            <PatientMenu />
            <Divider />
            <ListItem>
                <ListItemText
                    primary="delivery sheets"
                    primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'button' }}
                />
            </ListItem>
            <DeliverySheetMenu />
        </List>


 Patient-Menu
      <Fragment>
        <List component="div" disablePadding>
          <ListItem button
            component={Link}
            to={`${this.props.match.url}/patient/all_patients`}
            onClick={this.handleOnClick};              
          >
            <ListItemText 
              className='nested'
              style={{paddingLeft: 20 }}                      
              primary="Show all" 
              primaryTypographyProps={{variant:'subtitle2'}}
            />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Fragment>
```